# outputting errors to a logfile with echo output to the same logfile

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a ksh script that contains a bunch of echo statements that output to a log file like this:

```
echo "[$(date '+%c')] some text of a status" >> $lgfile
```

I'm trying to output the errors to the same file but can't seem to get it to work. The ksh file gets started from another scipt like this:

```
lgfile="$(date '+%Y'-'%m'-'%d'_'%H':'%M'_${ID}).log"
echo "[$(date '+%c')] $ID is now started" >> $lgfile
. ./process.ksh $lgfile $ID
```

I've tried running it like this:

```
. ./process.ksh $lgfile $ID 2>> $lgfile
```

but that seems to add the start of the lgfile and remove some stuff. I want to stderror to just append to the lgfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect stderr to stdout.

```
echo "[$(date '+%c')] some text of a status" >> $lgfile 2>&1
```